# Plot the average cross-validated AUC from caret package

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret, auc

I'm new to cross-validation. To understand the process, I just did k-10 cross-validation with 10 repeats, using the Caret package on my data using logistic regression with two predictors:

```
# creating hypothetical data  
x1 = rnorm(47, mean = 45, sd = 5); x2 = rnorm(107, mean = 50, sd = 3); 
z1 = rnorm(47, mean = 13, sd = 1.3); z2 = rnorm(107, mean = 15, sd = 2.3)
Y0 = rep("No", 107);Y1 = rep("Yes",47)
a = c(x2,x1); b = c(z2,z1); c = c(Y0,Y1); 
data = as.data.frame(cbind(c,a,b)); names(data) = c("Group","Class1","Class2"); data$Group = as.factor(data$Group)

library(caret);library(pROC)
set.seed(1); train.control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats = 10,
                          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, 
                          savePredictions = "all",classProbs = TRUE)                
set.seed(1); model <- train(Group ~ Class1+Class2, data = data, method = "glm", family="binomial",
             trControl = train.control)
```

Learning from previous a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366143/how-to-compute-roc-and-auc-under-roc-after-training-using-caret-in-r), I figured the following script would produce an "overall" cross-validated AUC plot

```
plot(roc(response = model$pred$obs, predictor = model$pred$Yes))
```

But this plot produces the concatenated observation/predicted value of all 10k x 10 repeats iterations, not something I want. Since the output AUC is an average of AUC of iterations, which is the same as mean(model$Resample$ROC), I want to plot this average AUC. 
Looking at the output of model$pred, I understand that the first 15 or so rows are the first fold of a specific repeat (as in model$pred$Resample), and the next 15 or so iteration is the second, and so on. 
I want to take/segment the vectors of predicted and observed values for each fold.Repeat., calculate the mean for each point, and then plot the average of ROC (cross-validated ROC/AUC). I conceptually get it, but I can't come up with the specific code (especially because the length of each iteration is different).

I also want to obtain 95%CI of the AUC and do the same process with another different variable and overlap the two cross-validated average AUCs to visually show the differences. Can someone solve this, please? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We can't reproduce your plot without `data`. And while one can guess that your code needs the `library(caret)` to work, it is unclear which `roc` function you use (from which package).

Comment: @scrameri I'm sorry, I can't provide the data. Thank you for your comments, though. I don't have any issue with the script (roc is from pROC and all necessary packages are installed). My question is, from the output of caret (model$pred), how to make a code to extract/segment the predicted (model$pred$CLASSNAME) and observed values (model$pred$obs) for each fold-repeat (model$pred$Resample) and get the average from each fold-repeat and plot that. Because there are 10 x 10 validation, it takes forever without a function. But the length of each validation set is different, so I'm stuck.

Comment: @scrameri, I just created a sample data so the script would run and edited the post. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the first part of your question correctly, you'd like to extract some statistics from each resample, and summarise them in some way.

To achive this, you could `sapply` a procedure `FUN` over all elements `X`, where `X` are your resamples. This way, it doesn't matter how many samples are predicted in each resample.

However, I'm not exactly sure which statistics you want to extract from the resamples (*mean from each point*?). In the following, I assume that you like to get the ROC curve for each resample.

**apply cross-validation to logistic regression model**

```r
library(caret)
library(pROC)
library(tidyverse)

train.control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats = 10,
                              summaryFunction = twoClassSummary, 
                              savePredictions = "all",classProbs = TRUE)                

set.seed(1)
model <- train(Group ~ Class1 + Class2, data = data, method = "glm",
               family = "binomial", trControl = train.control)
               
#> Warning in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): The metric "Accuracy" was not
#> in the result set. ROC will be used instead.
```

**per-resample [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) (receiver operating characteristic) curve**

Such an `sapply` solution should work regardless of how large each resample is, and for whatever you'd like to do in `FUN`, as long as `FUN` outputs a `data.frame`.

```r
# sapply roc(), bind as tibble with Resample as .id
dd.roc <- sapply(X = unique(model$pred$Resample),
                 FUN = function(x) {
                   r <- model$pred[model$pred$Resample == x,]
                   R <- roc(response = r$obs, predictor = r$Yes)
                   data.frame(sensitivities = R$sensitivities,
                              specificities = R$specificities)
                 }, simplify = F) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Resample") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  arrange(specificities)
#> Setting levels: control = No, case = Yes
#> Setting direction: controls < cases
#> [many more such warnings]


dd.roc
#> # A tibble: 1,640 × 3
#>    Resample     sensitivities specificities
#>    <chr>                <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 Fold01.Rep01             1             0
#>  2 Fold02.Rep01             1             0
#>  3 Fold03.Rep01             1             0
#>  4 Fold04.Rep01             1             0
#>  5 Fold05.Rep01             1             0
#>  6 Fold06.Rep01             1             0
#>  7 Fold07.Rep01             1             0
#>  8 Fold08.Rep01             1             0
#>  9 Fold09.Rep01             1             0
#> 10 Fold10.Rep01             1             0
#> # … with 1,630 more rows
```

**get overall [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) (receiver operating characteristic) curve**

```r
d.roc <- roc(response = model$pred$obs, predictor = model$pred$Yes)
#> Setting levels: control = No, case = Yes
#> Setting direction: controls < cases

d.roc <- data.frame(sensitivities = d.roc$sensitivities,
                    specificities = d.roc$specificities)
```

**plot**

```r
ggplot(dd.roc, aes(x=specificities,y=sensitivities))+
  # geom_point(colour = "tomato", alpha = 0.1) +
  # geom_density2d() +
  geom_path(aes(group = Resample, colour = "ROC per resample"), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_smooth(colour = "tomato", size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(data = d.roc, aes(colour = "ROC over all resamples"), size = 1.5) +
  ylim(0,1) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = 1, intercept = 1)) +
  scale_x_reverse(limit = c(1,0)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("seagreen","tomato"), name = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

**toy data**

```r
x1 = rnorm(47, mean = 45, sd = 5); x2 = rnorm(107, mean = 50, sd = 3); 
z1 = rnorm(47, mean = 13, sd = 1.3); z2 = rnorm(107, mean = 15, sd = 2.3)
Y0 = rep("No", 107);Y1 = rep("Yes",47)
a = c(x2,x1); b = c(z2,z1); c = c(Y0,Y1); 
data = data.frame(Group = factor(c), Class1 = a, Class2 = b)

# plot data
ggplot(data, aes(x = Class1, y = Class2, colour = Group)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>